# APM shows large executions of SQL after migration to Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle12c, apm

After migration from oracle 10c to 12c, there are many times where in intrascope we see large number of same sql executing large number of times, which is causing heap space issue.

Since code is same and issue did not appear in 10c, why it uis now causing issue after migration?

Example:

In java we have method repository. load(id)  which is called in for loop in many places . 
So this is sql we seen in intrascope APM where it was executed 500 000 times in 30 mins. and suddenly increases heap size to max.

This issues did not apprear in 10c

Below is APM heap space increased in 30 mins

[image]

SQL executions

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example, so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hello marstran , i have edited, let me know if needed anything

Comment: Adaptive Query Optimization. https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/adaptive-query-optimization-12cr1

Comment: Thanks ibre, you means to say there is some configuration we need to do in 12c ?

Comment: for information response time is very good 0.006 s , only it is exceuted many times